# Batch file stops after a series of pipes in XP

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, jq

I have a following batch file that retrieves data from a database in JSON format, extracts numbers and stores them:

```
set server=http://login:password@host:port
set db=PostgreSQL%%20DB

del IDs.txt
echo Section1 >> IDs.txt
curl "%server%/%db%/Section1" | jq .[] | jq .[] >> IDs.txt
echo Section2 >> IDs.txt
curl "%server%/%db%/Section2" | jq .[] | jq .[] >> IDs.txt
echo Section3 >> IDs.txt
curl "%server%/%db%/Section3" | jq .[] | jq .[] >> IDs.txt
...
```

It works under Windows 8, but under Windows XP it stops after the first curl-jq line. There are no errors. Retrieving numbers works correctly, but only once.

I tried to replace curl-jq calls with

```
cmd /c "curl %server%/%db%/Section3 | jq .[] | jq .[] >> IDs.txt"
```

but it didn't help.

What is wrong? Is there a way to make this work in XP?

Thanks in advance.

Update: here are examples of output JSON:

```
{"ids":[80001]}
```

or

```
{"ids":[12001,12002,12003,43120]}
```

What I need is just to extract the numbers as a column:

```
80001
```

or

```
12001
12002
12003
43120
```

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, you didn't copy the 64-bit build of jq from Win 8 to your XP box did you?

Comment: A valid question. Both `curl` and `jq` work correctly from the command line. It is "jq-win32.exe" from the official site. How to check if there are problems with `jq`?

Comment: Do you have `@echo off` set at the top of your script?  If so, try remarking it out (`rem @echo off`) and see whether the line which halts the script is evaluated the the way you composed it.  I'm wondering if there's something you aren't showing us.  Are the `curl | jq | jq` commands located within a parenthetical code block (an `if` statement or `for` loop)?  If so, you might need delayed expansion for `!server!` or `!db!`.

Comment: I don't have `echo off`. All lines are evaluated correctly. The produced result is correct, the only problem is that batch file does not continue to the second line.

The only thing I changed are server and section URLs.

curl | jq | jq lines are not inside a loop, but I do plan to put them into a `for ` loop later on. Will that add any more problems? I did try to replace echo-curl lines with 

`call :IDout Section1 %out% %server% %db%`

or similar calls to an external batch (and had to replace %%20 with %%%%20). The result was the same: execution stops after the IDs for Section1 are written.

Comment: Edit your question to show an example of the JSON, as well as the desired contents of IDs.txt, and I'll help you figure out a different road, one that doesn't depend on curl or jq but uses functionality already built into Windows.  Don't worry.  What I have in mind will still have a .bat extension.

Comment: @rojo: Ops! Another question from a rep-1 beginner that does not care to follow his/her question! This is the main reason I don't like to answer questions from new members... **`:(`**

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this may help you?

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      echo %%b
   )
)
```

Output example:

```
C:\> type input.txt
{"ids":[80001]}

C:\> test.bat
80001

C:\> type input.txt
{"ids":[12001,12002,12003,43120]}

C:\> test.bat
12001
12002
12003
43120
```

Comment: This answer deserves some love, even if OP is nowhere to be seen to give it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to use two invocations of `jq`, just use one.  Also, it's generally best to quote your `jq` filters when they're given on the command line.

You're dumping the values in the `ids` property, so:

```
jq ".ids[]"
```

[EDIT: using double-quotes works here for both Windows and many other platforms, but on non-Windows platforms, single-quotes are usually the best bet.]

Comment: This answer deserves some love, even if OP is nowhere to be seen to give it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script and see if it does what you want.  Rather than depending on cURL to fetch the JSON, it uses an XMLHTTPRequest.  Rather than depending on jq to deserialize the JSON, it uses the JavaScript JSON parser.  And unlike Aacini's solution, it works the same regardless of whether the JSON is minified, beautified, whatever.  Save it with a .bat extension.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

set "server=http://login:password@host:port"
set "db=PostgreSQL DB"

>IDs.txt cscript /nologo /e:Jscript "%~f0" "%server%" "%db%"

goto :EOF
@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid chimera

var XHR = WSH.CreateObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'),
    htmlfile = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    args = { 'server': WSH.Arguments(0), 'db': WSH.Arguments(1) },
    url = encodeURI(args.server + '/' + args.db + '/Section'),
    section = 0;

function fetch(url) {
    XHR.open('GET', url, true);
    XHR.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'XMLHTTP/1.0');
    XHR.send('');
    while (XHR.readyState != 4) { WSH.Sleep(50); }
    return XHR.status == 200 ? XHR.responseText : '';
}

// import JSON method from htmlfile COM object
htmlfile.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
var JSON = htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON;

// fetch JSON by section sequentially until 404 error
while ((response = fetch(url + ++section))) {
    WSH.Echo('Section' + section);
    ids = JSON.parse(response).ids;
    for (var i in ids) WSH.Echo(ids[i]);
}
```